# Classification Problem - Every record is a unique class

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I have thousands of records where each is a unique class. I think what this means is that, which ever ML algorithm I choose, I will not be able to execute a train/test split because the test split cannot be modelled. This is because there is only one record for each class, therefore there is no way the model could have trained for anything that is in the test split.

I can't justify introducing unseen records for prediction if my model cannot be validated.

Each record is similar to a generic accounting record with about 20 features. I thought about using KNN, but KNN would not be able to do a train/test split neither. How do I go about mitigating this? Is KNN the wrong model to use here?

Comment: You need to explain more about what you are exactly trying to do and what is the data that you are working on. Plus how is this task a classification task if you can't group records together into classes? Because what you are trying to do seems more relevant to a regression problem if you can't classify records into groups

Comment: If each record is associated with one unique class, and you have **thousands** of records. Then I doubt it is a classification problem anymore. You need to consider it, either as a clustering problem or as a regression problem. Show us a real sample of your dataset!